# como mostrar varios regitros de una tabla que su id este en otra con PDO?

Tags: php, sql, base-de-datos, datatables

quiero solo mostrar los datos de unas tablas relacionadas que serian eventos->temas->ponentes dos tienen sus id en otras y quisiera saber como mostrar los datos en pantalla nada mas, lo intente con inner join pero no me funciona o solo muestra un unico registro de cada tabla. aqu el codigo html

```
    <?php
     require 'funciones.php';
     $obj= new funciones();
     $publicacion = $obj->getPublicacion($_GET['blog_id']);
     //echo '<pre>',print_r($publicaciones),'</pre>';

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
     <head>
         <meta charset="UTF-8">
         <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style_SE.css">
         <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
         <title><?php echo $publicacion['titulo']?></title>
         <link rel="shortcut icon" type="text/x-icon" href="img/U.png">
         <script src="js/fontawesome-all.min.js"></script>
     </head>
     <body>
         <header>

             <div class="logo">

                 <img src="img/logo.jpg" width="100%" >
             </div>
             <div class="nave">
                 <nav>
                      <ul>
                         <li><a href="../index.php">Inicio</a></li>
                         <li><a href="#">constancias</a></li>
                         <li><a href="#">Contatos</a></li>
                         <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/"><i class="fab fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
                         <li><a href="https://twitter.com/"><i class="fab fa-twitter-square"></i></a></li>
                         <li><a href="https://www.instagram.com/?hl=es-la"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a></li>
                         <li><a href="Sistema_Eventos/login.html"><i class="fas fa-sign-in-alt"></i></a></li> 
                     </ul>
                 </nav>
             </div> 
         </header>


         <div class="main">
            <div class="artic">
                 <section ="prin">
                    <h2><?php echo $publicacion['titulo']?></h2>
                 <div class="row">
                    <?php echo $publicacion['fecha']?>
                     <?php echo $publicacion['tiempo']?>
                     <?php echo $publicacion['lugar']?>
                     <?php echo $publicacion['contenido']?>
                     <?php echo $publicacion['titulo_tema']?>
                     <?php echo $publicacion['ci']?>
                     <?php echo $publicacion['nombre']?>
                     <?php echo $publicacion['apellido']?>
                 </div>   
                 </section>
             </div>
         </div>


         <aside>
             <div class="extra">
             </div>
             </aside>


         <footer>
             <div class="pie"> 
                 <p>copyright UNERG 2018 / Decoration AzX</p>
             </div>
         </footer>
         <script src="css/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
         <script src=""></script>
     </body>
</html>
```

el codigo php

```
    <?php
    require 'int.php';
     class funciones{
        public function getPublicaciones(){
            global $link;
            $query = $link->prepare("SELECT * FROM eventos ");
            $query -> execute();
            return $query->fetchAll();
        }
        public function getPublicacion($id_Eventos){
            global $link;
            $query = $link->prepare("SELECT * FROM eventos WHERE id_Eventos = :id_Eventos");
            $query -> execute(['id_Eventos' => $id_Eventos ]);
            return $query->fetch();

        }
     }
?>
```

y aqui la base de datos, solo quiero mostrar la informacion de cada tabla por el id que tenga de la anterior osea un evento, 2 temas, 4 ponenets algo asi
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Sería algo más o menos así, el problema es que la pregunta no se entiende del todo: `SELECT COUNT(t.id_tema) temas, COUNT(p.id_ponentes) ponentes FROM eventos e INNER JOIN temas t ON e.id_Eventos=t.id_eventos INNER JOIN ponentes p ON t.id_temas=p.id_temas GROUP BY e.id_Eventos;` Es sólo una idea, puede que el `GROUP BY` deba ser otro, según cómo quieras agrupar los datos, puede que quieras más campos en el `SELECT`. Esas son algunas de las cosas que no quedan claras en la pregunta, no obstante la consulta que propongo puede darte una idea de cómo sería.

Comment: ok gracias lo voy a probar a ver que pasa

Comment: cuando copio y pego el codigo no muestra nada..por q sera?

Comment: Porque quizá no haya datos relacionados entre las tablas realmente. Prueba de forma individual con cada JOIN, por ejemplo. Consulta 1: `SELECT COUNT(t.id_tema) temas FROM eventos e INNER JOIN temas t ON e.id_Eventos=t.id_eventos GROUP BY e.id_Eventos;`  Consulta 2: `SELECT  COUNT(p.id_ponentes) ponentes FROM eventos e INNER JOIN ponentes p ON t.id_temas=p.id_temas GROUP BY e.id_Eventos;`

Comment: con el count no se que es lo que sucede pero cuando hago un inner join normal si muestra todas las tabla pero solo el pimer registro de cada una

Comment: Te muestra un solo registro porque estás agrupando, por eso el `GROUP BY`... si se lo quitas te mostrará todas las filas. Yo usé una combinación de `COUNT` y `GROUP_BY` porque entendí que lo que querías era contar el total de temas y de ponentes. Si no da resultados es porque parece que no pusiste registros relacionados realmente en cada tabla, o sea, mismo id de evento en las dos tablas implicadas, mismo id de tema en las dos tablas implicadas. Puedes probar a cambiar `INNER JOIN`  por `LEFT JOIN` también.